# Confused about Types.ObjectId and Schema.Types.ObjectId from Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, objectid

I'm trying to created nested schema with mongoose, attaching a user_id field for subdocuments. I found out this approach

```js
const {Schema} = require("mongoose");
var user_id = {
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:"User",
  },
```

but later i found that `Types` can be imported from mongoose on top level , but the definition of the ObjectId is very different from `Schema.Types`, as such

```js
const {Types} = require("mongoose");
var user_id = {
    type:new Types.ObjectId(),
    ref:"User",
  },
```

I couldn't find documentation on this nuance....I guess i should use a consistent approach across the app, so can someone help to explain?

*Edit: I think the one I should use should be consistent with the way _id is defined for the `User` table, but which one was it used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh i got it.

```js
newUser._id instanceof Types.ObjectId == true
```

so Types.ObjectId is the correct one to use.